# Configure dnsmasq to behave differently per interface

Tags: debian, dns, dnsmasq

I am trying to configure dnsmasq on Debian to provide DNS service on a wlan0 interface by redirecting all traffic to one single IP as follows.

```
address=/#/172.16.0.1
```

However, I don't want this to apply for the local services running on the server. I could not find on dnsmasq documentation how to do that. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Use two dnsmasq instances: one listening on `wlan0` and second listening on other interfaces.

You can configure the instance for `wlan0` with:

```
bind-interfaces
except-interface=lo
interface=wlan0
# ... more options
```

And for the other instance:

```
bind-interfaces
except-interface=wlan0
# ... more options
```